# Why does Objective-C use YES/NO macro convention instead of true/false?

Tags: objective-c, naming-conventions, boolean, convention

Most languages use the `true/false` keywords for boolean values.  I found that even Smalltalk is using `true/false`.  I know Objective-C is just borrowing concepts from Smalltalk, not the language itself, but I'm curious why it's using `YES/NO` instead of the more widely-used `true/false`.  Is there any historical reason?

Comment: That's an interesting question, and not something I would have thought to ask about.  Good idea.

Comment: "Instead of?" Both sets of macros work fine - use whichever seems appropriate in context.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Objective-C was designed to be (and still is) a strict superset of C. The creators worked very hard to ensure that they did not break compatibility with C in any way. They also tried to make their modifications somewhat obvious so that it would be easy to tell which parts of the code use Objective-C and which parts use plain C. Case in point, the `@` used to denote NSStrings rather than just using quotes. This allows plain C strings to coexist with the new ones.

C already had an informal system of TRUE/FALSE macros. I suspect the designers of Objective-C chose the YES/NO macros to avoid conflict and to make it obvious that the code is actually Objective-C. Notice also the usage `nil` for the 'empty' object rather than just modifying the behavior of good old NULL.

Comment: +1 for an answer that actually makes sense. Most other answers to this question around SO just said "because YES is easier to understand/read then TRUE".

Answer (score 4):

Objective-C is a very verbose language, all methods are very descriptive, and using YES/NO for boolean values instead of true/false makes it more human readable.

You would probably find the following conversation strange, if it happened in real life:
A: "Did you see the movie?"
B: "True"

If B had answered "yes" (or "no"), it would sound perfectly normal, and code looks more like plain english by using YES/NO instead of true/false.

Comment: Hmm... I'm not so sure about the "plain english" explanation. If their intention is to provide clarity, wouldn't it make more sense to follow decades of convention?

Comment: But Objective-C has used that convention for decades? Oh, you meant other languages... ;) The majority isn't always right. If you were designing a language, wouldn't you prefer that the language was the best it could be, rather than as compatible with other languages as possible? Judging by the readability of Objective-C compared to other languages, my guess is that the designers valued plain English higher than syntactic resemblance with other languages.

Comment: I see your point that the majority is not always right, but as a counter-example, I offer [Esperanto](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Esperanto), a created language that would make conversation with almost any human being possible, however it has not really caught on yet even though it's over a century old.

Answer (score 3):

Apple have always tried to make things easier to use.  If you read some system boolean methods and ask yourself what makes more sense to answer a boolean question with, either using  `YES|NO` or `TRUE|FALSE`, you'll see thank the answer is `YES|NO` in my opinion.

Otherwise you can always use `TRUE|FALSE` in your code.

Answer (score 2):

It is strange, but I find code is more readable using the `YES`/`NO` macros rather than `TRUE`/`FALSE` (which also work).

However, Objective-C is a superset of C99 now, so you should be using the C99 `boolean` type and `true` and `false` wherever possible.  I was toying with the idea of defining `yes` and `no` to `true` and `false` but have resisted it so far.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to think of this is that it's parallel evolution.

Objective-C's `BOOL` and `YES`/`NO` dates all the way back to early 1980s, and was likely intended to not only mimic other languages but miss C's future development. `_Bool`, `true`/`false` in C were only made part of the standard in 1999.

So are `YES` and `NO` historical? Yes. Are they only historical? No. Just as `NULL` is not the result of 3-3 in a pure sense (despite `NULL` often being defined as `0`, or casually usable if it were), `true` is not a value for `BOOL`.

You would not (I think) write this code:

```
int matches = NULL;
for (int i = 0; i<count; ++i) {
    if (array[i] == value) ++matches;
}
```

This is less obviously wrong, but it's on the same spectrum:

```
BOOL foundMatch = false;
for (int i = 0; i<count; ++i) {
    if (array[i] == value) {
        foundMatch = YES;
        break;
    }
}
```