# UIWebView - change size and fit content

Tags: html, ios, uiwebview

I want to download html content, then find out it's size (by calling javascript functions). After that I want to change `UIWebView` frame to that size. And html content should fill whole `UIWebView`.

I read documentation and similar questions here on stackoverflow. Nothing helped. I don't want to call **reload** method and download HTML from server **twice**. I get correct width and height of html, but after changing `UIWebView` frame size, html content doesn't fill the frame. (this code below is called in `- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView`)

```
NSNumberFormatter * f = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[f setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
NSNumber *width = [f numberFromString:[self.mediaWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"getContentWidth()"]];
NSNumber *height = [f numberFromString:[self.mediaWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"getContentHeight()"]];

self.mediaWebView.frame = CGRectMake(BORDER_WIDTH, BORDER_WIDTH, _frameWidth, _frameHeight);
self.mediaWebView.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, _frameWidth, _frameHeight);
```

Init code:

```
self.mediaWebView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(BORDER_WIDTH, BORDER_WIDTH, _frameWidth, _frameHeight)];
[self.mediaWebView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[self.mediaWebView setOpaque:FALSE];
[self.mediaWebView setUserInteractionEnabled:TRUE];
self.mediaWebView.scrollView.scrollEnabled = FALSE;
self.mediaWebView.scrollView.bounces = FALSE;
self.mediaWebView.delegate = self;
self.mediaWebView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeRedraw;
self.mediaWebView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];


NSString *stringUrl = @""// some URL

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:stringUrl];
[self.mediaWebView loadHTMLString:[self.questionView.question.mediaHtml description] baseURL:url];

self.mediaWebView.scalesPageToFit = TRUE;

[self addSubview:self.mediaWebView];
```

Comment: I found it out. It was enaught to change property scalesPageToFit to FALSE. HTML content didn't changed when I played with frame size of WebView. So I started with max size of webview, then get correct size from JS functions and at the end change frame size. Content never scaled(zoomed,...) and that was exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I described in comment below question. It was enaugh to set  scalesPageToFit to FALSE

Comment: Good point +1. You should however seriously consider using YES/NO instead of TRUE/FALSE. The functionally is the same, but in Objective C you are expected to use those values for BOOL. You can read here why: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6420987/why-does-objective-c-use-yes-no-macro-convention-instead-of-true-false