# iOS, boolean variables

Tags: ios, objective-c

In Objective-C I can initialize BOOL variable with YES or TRUE. Is there a reason for this?

```
BOOL test = false;
BOOL test = NO;
```

Are they the same?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/615702/is-there-a-difference-between-yes-no-true-false-and-true-false-in-objective-c

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6420987/why-does-objective-c-use-yes-no-macro-convention-instead-of-true-false

Comment: @Vinzzz Don't just post a link, vote to close as a duplicate.

Comment: Because everyone has a different favorite, and they didn't want to hurt anyone's feelings.  Does it matter?

Comment: Nothing bad in closing a question. I get hurt when I see downVote.

Comment: @maddy : I didn't know how to 'vote to close' a question. I see...I had to click that 'flag' and find the good item, ok !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`true` and `false` comes from c / c++

```
#ifndef __cplusplus
#define bool _Bool
#define true 1
#define false 0
```

`YES` and `NO` is from Objective-C

```
#if __has_feature(objc_bool)
#define YES             __objc_yes
#define NO              __objc_no
#else
#define YES             ((BOOL)1)
#define NO              ((BOOL)0)
#endif
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes. `false` is left over from C, `NO` is more prevalent in idiomatic iOS code and libraries.